# Serialize a map to YAML with a specific order

Tags: haskell, serialization, yaml, aeson

I use the `yaml` library to serialize a value of type `Map String t` (or some type t). The order in the resulting output is rather random, which is suboptimal, as the file should be human readable.

Is there a way to control the serialization order of a map? Or, probably closer to the core of the problem, an aeson `Object`? If not, what are suitable workarounds?

Comment: What about `sort . toList` ?

Comment: Lists of pairs are serialized differently than maps.

Comment: `object . map (\(k,v) -> yourTypeToText k .= v ) . sort . toList`

Comment: Have you verified that? Objects are unordered (hash)maps themselves.

Comment: My bad, just got lucky with the values I tested it with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 0.8.13, the `yaml` package contains the [`Data.Yaml.Prettty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.11.5.0/docs/Data-Yaml-Pretty.html) module. This allows you to configure how to pretty-print yaml documents, including ordering fields using `setConfCompare`

In one of my own projects, I [started using it](https://github.com/entropia/tip-toi-reveng/commit/fe8c4c4ba7f63230156c81d77eb99cb9fef2b9a7) with a change like this:

```
 writeTipToiYaml :: FilePath -> TipToiYAML -> IO ()
-writeTipToiYaml out tty = encodeFile out tty
+writeTipToiYaml out tty =
+    SBC.writeFile out (encodePretty opts tty)
+  where
+    opts = setConfCompare (compare `on` fieldIndex) defConfig
+    fieldIndex s = fromMaybe (length fields) $ s `elemIndex` fields
+    fields = map T.pack
+        [ "product-id"
+        , "comment"
+        , "welcome"
+        , "media-path"
+        , "gme-lang"
+        , "init"
+        , "scripts"
+        , "language"
+        , "speak"
+        , "scriptcodes"
+        ]
```

Comment: This works at the top level, but nested data structures don't have their fields ordered by the comparator :(

Comment: Ugh, really? That sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about this comment.  No, it does work.  I was just horribly mistaken  Thank you for reminding me to debunk my own comment.

Answer (score 1):

With `yaml`, or `aeson` on which it is based, it is currently not easily possible, [says the `yaml` author](https://github.com/snoyberg/yaml/issues/37), but he has started some experimental support for it in the form of the [Data.Yaml.Builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.8.10.1/docs/Data-Yaml-Builder.html) module.